# java.lang.IllegalStateException at android.media.MediaRecorder.start when calling MediaRecorder.start in onLongClickListener

Tags: android, illegalstateexception, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

I want to start recording a voice message with `MediaRecorder` when I hold down a button. I am getting an `IllegalStateException` when trying to start recording in a `onLongClickListener`.

The error I am receiving as noted in the stacktrace is on Line 219: `recorder.start()`

**Why is this happening?**

```
btnSendVoice.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            isVoiceButtonHeld = true;
            startRecording();
            return false;
        }
    });

    btnSendVoice.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            view.onTouchEvent(event);

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if (isVoiceButtonHeld) {
                    isVoiceButtonHeld = false;
                    stopRecording();
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

private void startRecording() {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Recording Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    filename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/audiotest.3gp";

    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setOutputFile(filename);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

    try { recorder.prepare(); } 
    catch (IOException e) { Log.e("MediaRecorder", "prepare() failed"); }
    recorder.start();
}

private void stopRecording() {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Recording Finished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    recorder.stop();
    recorder.release();
    recorder = null;
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    // Free up resources from MediaRecorder when leaving Fragment
    if (recorder != null) {
        recorder.release();
        recorder = null;
    }
}
```

**LogCat**

```
07-15 16:24:32.256: E/MediaRecorder(4227): start failed: -38
07-15 16:24:32.256: D/AndroidRuntime(4227): Shutting down VM
07-15 16:24:32.256: W/dalvikvm(4227): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41551ba8)
07-15 16:24:32.406: E/AndroidRuntime(4227): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-15 16:24:32.406: E/AndroidRuntime(4227): Process: com.walintukai.lfdate, PID: 4227
07-15 16:24:32.406: E/AndroidRuntime(4227): java.lang.IllegalStateException
07-15 16:24:32.406: E/AndroidRuntime(4227):     at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
07-15 16:24:32.406: E/AndroidRuntime(4227):     at com.walintukai.lfdate.ChatFragment.startRecording(ChatFragment.java:219)
07-15 16:24:32.406: E/AndroidRuntime(4227):     at com.walintukai.lfdate.ChatFragment.access$4(ChatFragment.java:206)
07-15 16:24:32.406: E/AndroidRuntime(4227):     at com.walintukai.lfdate.ChatFragment$3.onLongClick(ChatFragment.java:132)
07-15 16:24:32.406: E/AndroidRuntime(4227):     at android.view.View.performLongClick(View.java:4474)
07-15 16:24:32.406: E/AndroidRuntime(4227):     at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:18418)
07-15 16:24:32.406: E/AndroidRuntime(4227):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-15 16:24:32.406: E/AndroidRuntime(4227):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-15 16:24:32.406: E/AndroidRuntime(4227):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-15 16:24:32.406: E/AndroidRuntime(4227):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5050)
07-15 16:24:32.406: E/AndroidRuntime(4227):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 16:24:32.406: E/AndroidRuntime(4227):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-15 16:24:32.406: E/AndroidRuntime(4227):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
07-15 16:24:32.406: E/AndroidRuntime(4227):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
07-15 16:24:32.406: E/AndroidRuntime(4227):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />` permission to record audio on your `Manifest.xml` file.

Edit: Your `onTouchListener` is interfering with `onLongClickListener` and may be stopping your `MediaRecorder` right after it is initialized and before it starts or even stopping it when the recorder is null. That gives origin to your `Exception`.

Note that If you comment the line `view.onTouchEvent(event);`, it starts recording, but it has an unpredictable behaviour from that moment on, according to the user action.

Be aware that the `Event.ACTION_CANCEL` is possible to happen on your scenario and must be taken into account in order to have your `recorder` stopped.

Make sure to check if your `recorder` is not null before calling `stop()`.

Comment: I already put that in there. I had the record, stop and play functions working earlier when I used regular buttons. This problem arose when I put the record function in a `onLongClickListener`.

Comment: Is it crashing when you long click the first time or the second time?

Comment: It is crashing on long clicking the first time.

Comment: Also, to make your implementation more robust, check if `mediarecorder` is not null before calling `stop()`.